# how to send query?

Tags: mysql, sql

If I send the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as total, SUM(ABS(AMOUNT)) AS Total_Amount 
    FROM success_log  
    WHERE TRANSACTION = 'success' ) t1 
CROSS JOIN  (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as success_total,  SUM((AMOUNT))  AS success_Amount 
    FROM success_log  WHERE 
    TRANSACTION = 'success' ) t2
CROSS JOIN  (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as Fail_total, SUM(ABS(AMOUNT)) AS Fail_Amount 
    FROM success_log  
    WHERE TRANSACTION = 'cancle') t3
```

result:

[image]

but I want result:

[image]

how to send query??

schema is 
[image]

Comment: How does `success_Amount` 3013 calculated? Please provide schema & sample data.

Comment: yes success_Amount is Total_Amount - Fali_Amount and success_total is total- Fail_total

Comment: I suggest using `SELECT TRANSACTION,count(*) as count, SUM(ABS(AMOUNT)) as total FROM success_log  GROUP BY TRANSACTION ORDER BY TRANSACTION` and then use the application code to display the columns correctly. In your question total and success_total are from the same query so they of course will have the same result.

Comment: Why do you use `ABS(amount)` in some of the queries, but just `amount` in others?

Comment: And why do you store `Amount` as `VARCHAR` rather than `INT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
SELECT total,
       Total_amount,
       (total - Fail_total) AS success_total,
       (Total_amount - Fail_amount) AS success_Amount,
       Fail_total,
       Fail_amount
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as total,
           SUM(ABS(AMOUNT)) AS Total_Amount
    FROM success_log
    WHERE TRANSACTION = 'success'
) t1 
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as Fail_total, 
           SUM(ABS(AMOUNT)) AS Fail_Amount 
    FROM success_log
    WHERE TRANSACTION = 'cancle'
) t3
```

Just to explain, your second cross join t2 wasn't returning the correct result so I used t1 and t3's original columns and added two other columns by subtracting their difference to show the success total and amount.

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what was wrong and how you fixed it. And make the code readable.

Answer (score 0):

You must need remove the ***Where*** condition in total_amount calculation select query...

Hope this Helpfull...

```
SELECT
  total,Total_Amount,success_total,success_Amount,Fail_total,Fail_Amount
FROM
  ( 
    SELECT
      COUNT() as total
      , SUM(ABS(AMOUNT)) AS Total_Amount 
    FROM
      success_log 
  ) t1 
  CROSS JOIN ( 
    SELECT
      COUNT() as success_total
      , SUM((AMOUNT)) AS success_Amount 
    FROM
      success_log 
    WHERE
      TRANSACTION = 'success'
  ) t2 
  CROSS JOIN ( 
    SELECT
      COUNT(*) as Fail_total
      , SUM(ABS(AMOUNT)) AS Fail_Amount 
    FROM
      success_log 
    WHERE
      TRANSACTION = 'cancel'
  ) t3
```